# Meteor: templates included in markdown do not call onRendered hook

Tags: meteor, markdown

I use markdown in a template, and include another template in markdown, as follows:

```
<template name="hello">
  {{#markdown}}

  {{> subtemplate}}

  {{/markdown}}

</template>

<template name="subtemplate">
  <p>Something to show</p>
</template>
```

Then in javascript, I have:

```
Template.subtemplate.onRendered(
  function() {
    console.log("Visited");
    return;
  }
)
```

On the page, I do see "Something to show". However, the onRendered hook is not called, as I don't see "Visited" in the console.

If I move the subtemplate outside markdown:

```
<template name="hello">
  {{#markdown}}

  {{/markdown}}

  {{> subtemplate}}

</template>
```

I do see the "Visited" in the console.

So, anyway to trigger onRendered hook inside markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's currently no way to put a template inside `markdown` helper and have it work interactively. It also applies to event handlers not only `onRendered` hooks.

The reason this is happening is that what `markdown` effectively does is it transfer all it's contents to text, then it passes it through a markdown parser and finally renderers the resulting text. The consequence is that the structure of your `views` get lost in the process.

In fact, the helper was not designed to handle a lot of html content inside of it. Instead you should probably pass only single chunks of text to the `markdown` helper and try to avoid putting templates inside if they contain some additional logic apart from rendering stuff, e.g. event handlers.

Comment: Thanks. This is really unfortunate.